# Display the result of binary image in an HTML img tag

Tags: php, html

I have managed to display an image stored as `VARBINARY` when using `echo`:

```
<?php

$image_varbinary_string = "FFD8FFE000.......FFD9";
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo hex2bin($image_varbinary_string);
```

It displays the image.

But I want to display inside an `<img>` tag.

I then tried to convert the `hex` to `base64` instead of binary and output inside the `<img>` tag, but it didn't work:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($image_varbinary_string);?>" >
```

Comment: You need to convert to binary *and then* base64

Comment: Or set the img tag's href to the URL of your first script (the one which echoes the image content)

Comment: Thank you guys, both good ideas, I will see which works better in my case